# Como incluir arquivo gerado no php no mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

Estou usando a biblioteca `mpdf`para tentar exibir em `pdf` um arquivo criado em `php` mas estou com dificuldades de fazer o mesmo funcionar, creio que a forma que estou tentando não seja a correta.
O arquivo `php` contem `php` e `html` em sua estrutura e não vai ter como ser diferente, mas se isso for um empecilho para o funcionamento também gostaria de alguma orientação.

O que tenho é isso:

```
  define('MPDF_PATH', 'class/mpdf/');
  // include(MPDF_PATH.'mpdf.php');
  include('../_comp/externos/mpdf60/mpdf.php');
  $mpdf = new mPDF();
  $mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');
  $mpdf->Output();
  exit();
```

Onde está o:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');
```

Tentei colocar um include, mas não deu certo, depois tentei com um iframe, mas nada também.

Tentei usar o file_get_contents() como sugerido, mas o retorno é esse.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou utilizar a função [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) especificando a URL de acesso ao arquivo PHP desejado? Desta forma o servidor irá analizar o arquivo e retornar apenas o código HTML gerado.

Comment: Olá @AndersonCarlosWoss, sim fiz um teste, mas está vindo a página toda bagunçada com php, vou colocar o que retorna na pegunta.
Valeu pela dica.

Comment: Você está utilizando algum servidor PHP, como o Apache?

Comment: Pois parece que está tentando recuperar o conteúdo do arquivo sem interpretá-lo. Você pode também utilizar o próprio servidor nativo do PHP, através do comando `php -S` e chamar `file_get_contents("http://localhost:8000/arquivo.php")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro que você faça as pesquisas fora do include e utilize str_replace para trocar as variaveis do arquivo que file_get_contents pegou. No arquivo ficaria assim:

```
// seu arquivo que o file get contents pega
Endereço: %ENDERECO%
// seu php:
$file = file_get_contents('arquivo');
$file = str_replace(%ENDERECO%,$Retorno->Endereco, $file);

$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($file);
$mpdf->Output();
exit();
```

Dessa forma, o PHP irá trocar a parte onde está %ENDERECO% pelo que tem no $Retorno->Endereco, e assim, exibir o endereço e não o código em PHP.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado pela grande ajudar @Bruno Folle.